# How to allow text to spill outside div

Tags: html, css

For a simple example, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpp9B/): the text is supposed to be in one line, but it's broken down into three because of how small the div is. How do I *let* the text spill out of the div without it wrapping?

**Html:**

```
<div style="width: 20px;">Some text here</div>
```

**Result:**

```
Some
text
here
```

I want this:

```
Some text here
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 20px; white-space: nowrap;">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, will accept when I can. @MrJones What is the difference?

Comment: @MrJones I see then. Is it possible to have it work only for that one div though? Right now if I make a parent that's small, it doesn't affect the inner div's content.

Comment: Actually, the text overflows the div's width. Put a border on the div and you will see it. If you don't want other elements inside the div to behavior this way, just put the text inside a span element and move the white-space property to it.

Answer (score 4):

When a div has the attribute `white-space: no-wrap`, its child elements inherit the same property. If you would like child elements to wrap, you can use `white-space: normal;`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QDkr/)

Of course this works, but if the amount of divs using `normal` out-weighs the amount of divs using `nowrap`, I would suggest isolating the `nowrap` text by placing it in its own div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3nSL/1/)